# Waiting For GET Requests in For Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, get, axios

I am trying to make a number of GET requests to a webserver using Axios and Node. I use an asynchronous function to take an array of values, to make requests to unique URLs on the same website.

Each time the loop runs, I push the response to an array called "results."

When the loop finishes, the asynchronous function ends, and I tack on a `.then` function, passing it the returned value. I then log that to the screen.

**My problem is that the return statement fires before my requests are run. In other words, an empty array is logged, and *then* all of the requests are completed.**

How do I only return the results of my for loop to the asynchronous function after the GET requests are completed, and the array is filled with values?

Thanks for your help, here is the code:

```
const axios = require("axios");

var loop = [about,home,products,thanks]
var i;

const results = [];

const test = async () => {
    for(i = 0; i < loop.length; i++) {
        axios.get(`https://examplewebsite.com/${loop[i]}`)
            .then((response,body) => {
                results.push(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    };
    // THIS IS NOT CORRECT, IT CAUSES MY RESULTS TO BE RETURNED IMMEDIATELY
    return results;
}

test().then((results) => {
    console.log(results); // Currently outputs --> [ ]  
});
```

Comment: You're missing the `await` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that the return statement fires before my requests are run. In other words, an empty array is logged, and then all of the requests are completed.

You're not keeping reference to each of the Promise Chains you've created with `axios.get()` so you can't await them.

Post initialization, the above code executes like this:

1. Call `test()`
2. Iterate and create each request with `axios.get()`
3. Return `results`
4. `.then((results) => console.log(results)` is invoked and `results` are printed as `[]`
5. Process checks if any async work is being awaited - Nothing is being awaited
6. Process exits

It would've taken at least the next turn of the Event Loop for even one of your requests to have been handled. However, since your code executes in a single turn of the even loop, it runs all the code you wrote except the response handler attached to `axios.get()`. If you want to a more detailed explanation of what happens on each turn of the Event Loop and how it all works, you can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).

You need to return a reference to each Promise returned from `axios.get()`. Instead of storing their responses in an Array, store the Promises from `axios.get()`. Even though you're using `async/await` syntax, you still need to use `Promise.all()` to await more than one Promise at a once. `Promise.all()` can be used to await all of the request promise chains stored in your Array.

The above can be written more concisely using `Array#map` to iterate over a list of items and return an Array of Promise results.

```
const axios = require("axios");

const baseURL = 'http://examplewebsite.com/'        
const requestList = items => Promise.all(
  items.map(key => (
    axios.get(`${baseUrl}${key}`)
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  )
)

requestList(['about', 'home', 'products', 'thanks'])
  .then(results => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: Are you forgetting a parentheses here? It's not working for me.